# Ctags not working with .inc-files

Tags: emacs, ctags

I would love to use tags inside Emacs, like Vim does. However, I have some problems to set it ## Setup:
GNU Emacs GUI version 25.0.5.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) 
[Compiled from Harroogan Emacs.](https://bitbucket.org/Haroogan/emacs-for-windows/)

Projectile and Helm, using the latest version of Projectile/Helm from MELPA

Exuberant Ctags binary 58 for Windows

Windows 7 x64 bit.

### Actions:

The binary `ctags.exe` is in the PATH, and respons when I call it from command line in Windows with `ctags --help`.

I tried various things to create a TAGS file, without any result. One thing that I seem to have results, is with the help of the package `projectile`. But it gives me weird results.

When I'm inside a project, currently the buffer `index.php` is being opened. Inside that buffer, I regenate tags file with `projectile-regenate-tags`, with <kbd>C-c p R</kbd>.

The messages buffer gives me the following:

```
Starting a new list of tags tables
Making tags-file-name local to Dev/digiloket3/TAGS while let-bound!
```

I see the file TAGS is being created in the project root.

The directory root structure is like this:

```
index.php
.projectile
|- INCLUDE
    |- AJAX
    |- SCRIPTS
    |- PHP
```

### Issue:

Then I visit the tag list with `find-tag` (<kbd>g C-]</kbd>). When  I notice I don't get all variables and class/functions that are defined in the project.
When I call the `helm-etags-select`, I see the directory/file next to the tag. And what confuses me, is that only functions/classes and variables from files in the directory `AJAX` are being visible in the tag list, and not the variables/classes/functions from the files in the directory `PHP`.

Then I manually creating the TAGS file with in the command prompt with the right directory on `ctags -R`.

With no help.

All files in the folder PHP are called ****.inc.

When I renamed one of the files to ****.php, then they're popping up in my ctags table.

So the real issue here is how I could tell projectile/ctags to recognize .inc files as PHP-files, or index it

But I'm also open for another things to create a TAGS table on Windows platform with the `ctags` available on command line.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man ctags` for starters (if you can do so in Windows? There is [documentation](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html) available in any case.)

Assigning file extensions for a language is done with `--langmap`. Run the following command to see how that argument works:
`ctags --langmap=php:+.inc.foo.bar --list-maps=php`

So in your case, you would probably use something like this to generate your TAGS file:
`ctags -e -R --langmap=php:+.inc`

Tangentially, note also the options listed when you run `ctags --list-kinds=php`. You can then control which of those will be used: `ctags --php-kinds=-v-j --list-kinds=php`

Comment: Any idea how I could specify where the TAGS-file should be placed with tags? I found nothing about this in `man ctags`, only about which filename the TAGS file should have.

Comment: Try using the -f option to specify the output file. You also probably want to use -e to create a TAGS file for use with Emacs.